# Interoperating Async/await, @MainActor and DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, swift-concurrency

Say I have this code:

```swift
class Presenter {
    var viewToUpdate: UIView!
    
    func updateUI() {
        viewToUpdate.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

class ShinyNewAsyncAwaitClass {
    func doAsyncAwaitThing() async {
        // make network call or something
    }
}

class OtherClassThatICantUpdateToAsyncAwaitYet {
    func doOldClosureBasedThing(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // make network call or something
        completion()
    }
}

class TheClassThatUsesAllThisStuff {
    var newClass: ShinyNewAsyncAwaitClass!
    var oldClass: OtherClassThatICantUpdateToAsyncAwaitYet!
    var presenter: Presenter!
    
    func doSomethingWithNewClass() {
        Task {
            await self.newClass.doAsyncAwaitThing()
            
            // ---->>> What do I do here? <<<<----
            await self.presenter.updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    func doSomethingWithOldClass() {
        oldClass.doOldClosureBasedThing {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.presenter.updateUI()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func justUpdateTheView() {
        self.presenter.updateUI()
    }
}
```

In short, I have three classes. One I can update to async/await, the other I can't, and one that uses both. Both need access to a function that updates UI, both will need to access that function on the main thread.

I saw somewhere I can add `@MainActor` to the `updateUI` function, but in cases where I'm already on the main thread and I just want to call `updateUI`, like in `justUpdateTheView` I get this error:

> Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'updateUI()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
>
> Add '@MainActor' to make instance method 'justUpdateTheView()' part of global actor 'MainActor'

I can't define `justUpdateTheView` as `@MainActor`, because we're trying to update our project to the new concurrency stuff slowly and this would cause a chain reaction of changes that need to be made.

What to do for the best? Can I do something like this:

```swift
func doSomethingWithNewClass() {
    Task {
        await self.newClass.doAsyncAwaitThing()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.presenter.updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles, but are there any gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: Why not make a "copy of" justUpdateTheView function and mark that as MainActor?

Comment: @Shadowrun because in real life, `justUpdateTheView` is big and I'd end up duplicating a ton of logic (and this isn't the only example in the project either).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't you update the old class to async/await (using `withCheckedContinuation(...)` for instance)?

Comment: @LouisLac No because the old class is used by multiple other classes. Honestly anything other than being able to interoperate here will lead to a world of pain.

Comment: Maybe you can keep the two implementations in the old class (completion-bases and async/await-based). For instance you could define the async/await version in an extension just for convenience when using the new concurrency features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to run the UI code on the `MainActor`:

```swift
func doSomethingWithNewClass() {
    Task {
        await self.newClass.doAsyncAwaitThing()
        
        await MainActor.run {
            self.presenter.updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In GCD, we used to encumber the caller with the burden of making sure it dispatched the call to the right queue.

In Swift concurrency, we isolate the called function to the correct actor, and the compiler will automatically warn us if we ever attempt to call it directly from a function not isolated to the same actor. E.g., as you noted:

> I saw somewhere I can add `@MainActor` to the `updateUI` function …

Yes, that is prudent. So you might do:

```swift
class Presenter {
    var viewToUpdate: UIView!

    @MainActor
    func updateUI() {
        viewToUpdate.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Or, better, in the case of a “presenter” (whose whole purpose is to interact with the view), isolate the whole type to the main actor:

```swift
@MainActor
class Presenter {
    var viewToUpdate: UIView!

    func updateUI() {
        viewToUpdate.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

You then said:

> … but in cases where I'm already on the main thread and I just want to call `updateUI`, like in `justUpdateTheView` I get this error:
>
> > Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'updateUI()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
> >
> > Add '@MainActor' to make instance method 'justUpdateTheView()' part of global actor 'MainActor'

So, perhaps needless to say, the above actor-isolated `updateUI` that solves your `doSomethingWithNewClass` question, reducing it simply to:

```swift
func doSomethingWithNewClass() {
    Task {
        await newClass.doAsyncAwaitThing()
        await presenter.updateUI()        
    }
}
```

No manual `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` or `MainActor.run {…}` is needed.

And then, re `justUpdateTheView`, you can do:

```swift
func justUpdateTheView() {
    Task {
        await presenter.updateUI()
    }
}
```

Or, as the compiler suggested:

```swift
@MainActor
func justUpdateTheView() {
    presenter.updateUI()
}
```

(Personally, I would lean towards the former rather than sprinkling various service classes with `@MainActor`, but both work.)

Anyway, once you have isolated `updateUI` to the main actor, the `MainActor.run {…}` is no longer necessary. IMHO, when I find myself using `MainActor.run {…}`, I treat it as code-smell. (The exception to this rule is where you want to call a whole series of separate functions isolated to the main actor, you might wrap the group of them within a `MainActor.run {…}` to have one context switch as opposed to a series of them.)

---

Two asides:

1. Until such point that you have an opportunity to refactor that legacy API, I would go ahead and give it an `async` wrapper for the time being. Xcode actually provides a “Refactor” tool to do this for you:

   [image]

   Then you end up with:

   [image]

   Or, if this is in a codebase that you can’t edit, move this wrapper into an extension:

   ```swift
   extension OtherClassThatICantUpdateToAsyncAwaitYet {
       func doOldClosureBasedThing() async {
           await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
               doOldClosureBasedThing() {
                   continuation.resume(returning: ())
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Sure, you undoubtedly want to properly refactor the old API to use Swift concurrency, but the above provides a temporary wrapper that you can use until you get around to that. It only takes a few seconds and it saves you from encumbering your new code with legacy patterns.
2. I would advise caution in using `Task {…}` as that is *unstructured concurrency* (meaning that you lose task cancelation). The `Task {…}` is useful if you *have to* bridge from a synchronous context to an asynchronous one, but otherwise, use it with discretion.

   E.g., using our above wrapper and `updateUI` that is isolated to the main actor, it reduces `TheClassThatUsesAllThisStuff` to something that stays within structured concurrency:

   ```swift
   class TheClassThatUsesAllThisStuff {
       var newClass: ShinyNewAsyncAwaitClass!
       var oldClass: OtherClassThatICantUpdateToAsyncAwaitYet!
       var presenter: Presenter!

       func doSomethingWithNewClass() async {
           await newClass.doAsyncAwaitThing()
           await presenter.updateUI()              // automatically isolated to main actor
       }

       func doSomethingWithOldClass() async {
           await oldClass.doOldClosureBasedThing() // using our wrapper for now
           await presenter.updateUI()              // automatically isolated to main actor
       }

       func justUpdateTheView() async {
           await presenter.updateUI()              // automatically isolated to main actor
       }
   }
   ```

---

For what it is worth, in WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194?time=1290), they walk us through the transition from `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` to `MainActor.run {…}` to `@MainActor`-isolation. They even walk through the aforementioned edge-case where one might still use `MainActor.run {…}`. By the way, while I tried to drop you into the relevant portion of that video, the whole video is a nice, practical example of refactoring a legacy codebase.